# Detecting a double press on key in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to detect whether a user quickly presses a keyboard key twice, a double press. The pressing of the key is an NSEvent, and is caught by this method:

```
- (void)sendEvent:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSString* keysPressed = [theEvent characters];
    if ( [keysPressed isEqualToString:@" "] )
    {
        if(theEvent.type==NSKeyDown)
            NSLog(@"spaceDown");
        if(theEvent.type==NSKeyUp)
            NSLog(@"spaceUp");
    }
}
```

The log statements do in fact appear upon pressing and releasing the space bar, but now I want to detect if the user double taps the space bar, and distinguishing that from two individual presses. I think we'd have to create a custom solution to this.

How can I detect if two space bar key press events were, say, 0.3 seconds apart (thus making it a double press), and then performing a certain action if that condition is met?

Comment: Not inherently familiar with Cocoa, but a simple solution is to get the start time, `NSDate *startTime = [NSDate date];` when a key is pressed, `NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = [startTime timeIntervalSinceNow];` to get the elapsed time in milliseconds, and then act.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least 2 possible solutions to this.

1. Store the current system time, then compare to the last stored time.
2. Set a `BOOL doubleKeypress = YES`, then kick off an `NSTimer` with fire delay `0.3` to set `doubleKeypress = NO`.

In both cases you'll need to make sure you only check against previous presses of **that key**, so maybe store the `BOOL`s or times with an associated `keyCode` from the `NSEvent`.

It's made easier in that you can always overwrite an existing "previous event" since you're only detecting double keypresses and thus you only ever need to track 1 previous keypress. Make sure to set it to `nil` if you do fire a double keypress though (or else you'll fire 2 double key events in 3 keypresses, etc)!